# Assign loss calculated outside of graph to Pytorch model

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

I need to find a way to use a non-pytorch loss function on a pytorch model.  Short of rewriting the pytorch loss system, is there a way to assign the calculated loss to the model graph so it may be used with `.backwards`? Would it be feasible to create an artificial computational graph?

Comment: You can, but you will need to implement a custom backward method to correctly propagate the gradients. 
This will require some understanding of backprop and calculus as you'll need to write code to compute and gradients of your loss function and apply them to the incoming gradients. You can find more info about this in the [extending `torch.autograd`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html#extending-torch-autograd) section of the docs.

Comment: Ok, I think I am just going to save the .grad_fn for before the output layer and then manually find the second layer's loss and add the fn to it and let pytorch do the rest with .backward(). thanks for the help!

Comment: If possible, you could re-implement the loss such that it accepts pytorch tensors and let autograd figure it out for you. Something that accept a numpy array should be pretty easy. What does the non-pytorch loss function look like?

Comment: I am using the model as a data processor for an LGBM regressor and trying to train it on that regressor's loss.